# Should the [osx] tag be renamed to [macos]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

With the rename from OS X to macOS, should the tag be renamed too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[osx](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osx) → [macos](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macos) ✔︎

Just like that, all 16.5k [osx](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osx) questions are now [macos](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macos) questions! With what I presume was a chat between moderators outside of this meta question, bmike has reversed the synonym, such that [osx](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osx) → [macos](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macos). [Enjoy the shiny new badges!](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/badges/188/macos?userid=37797)

Also, since this change occurred quite suddenly, it seems like no-one thought about the tag wiki and of course it's now disappeared. I've updated the tag wiki of [macos](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macos) based on the prior tag wiki.

Comment: @bmike was busy on that a few days ago, see https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6IxT.png. Thanks for updating the tag.

Answer (score 31):

Only the newer versions will be called **macOS**, the older ones will still be called **OS X Cat-of-choice**. I would propose to go with a synonom instead of a renaming.

Today (June 2016), the synonym points [macos](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macos) -> [osx](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osx) so that we can decide at a later date to flip things around. If there is an answer that makes a strong argument for never merging the two, we might want to undo the synonym so that the [macos](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macos) questions are distinct.

Comment: Which direction would you suggest for the synonym?

Comment: Looking forward, having `osx` as a synonym for `macOS` is probably the better way (even if it hurts at first :-)

Comment: I agree with Patrix that one tag seems much better for the site. Unless there's a large consensus or some other reasoning we haven't considered, making the swap from mac being a synonym for os to os being a synonym to mac is trivial, instant, and reversible.

Comment: I think that legacy software would need a tag as well (ie. Mac OS 9 and older).

Comment: I agree with the above posts, the new os should be tagged 'macos' not to be confused with 'osx'. I say that keeping in mind that we are likely to encounter a great many things specific to 'macos' that did not affect or exist in 'osx' over the coming years. Even though some overlap will obviously exist between the two. I agree we should also find a tag for legacy mac software, perhaps 'maclegacy' or 'macclassic', or both as I know 'MacOS9 Classic' was often referred to as 'Classic' when running under OS X 10.

Comment: There is http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/classic-mac-os already :-)

Comment: I strongly agree that [tag:osx] should be a synonym for [tag:macos] and not the other way around. Apple is starting to retroactively [refer to pre-10.12 releases as macOS](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/256088), so I believe that we should follow their lead.

Comment: @patrix when should this change occur (or will it)? It always throws me off to see the `osx` tag! :)

Comment: @SkeletonBow Stay tuned :)

Comment: @patrix It was changed! I just saw the answer (and the tag). Ich danke Euch!

Comment: @SkeletonBow Der Dank gebührt bmike, der hat die Arbeit schlussendlich gemacht :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think that [osx](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osx) is a decent tag for the most part. [osx](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osx) refers to the modern version(s) of Apple's Operating System, which is titled as OS X. Earlier versions, before the 'OS X' line started (named after the big cats), were simply named Mac OS <insert version name and number here> - 'X' was added after Mac OS version 9. As such, I would think that the tag, [macos](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macos) would refer to legacy Apple Computer software, instead of newer software. Nonetheless, I would welcome the new tag! :)

Comment: @grgarside Thanks for fixing my formatting GrGarside. I missed that...

Comment: I don't think there are any questions here re Mac OS <= 9. Using tacos tag for just these will cause a lot of confusion. Most people won't realise it is for the old OS and most people won't read the tag wiki so no documentation will help. So most things tagged macos will be for the new OS no matter what we do

Comment: @Mark mhmm tacOS :)

Comment: @TopHatProductions115 The X was dropped with macOS 10.12 Sierra, so the macOS tag now refers to OS 9 and 10, depending on the specific version.

Comment: In that case, I suppose that a tag like [tag:osx] can only be used for a small range of Operating System versions. Thanks for the update.